# How to replace get_profile() in Django 1.10

Tags: django

I have upgraded from a much older version to Django 1.10 and I have probably about 30 calls to get_profile() throughout my entire codebase.

I have read on SO and the docs, but I am still not understanding how to replace this functionality now that get_profile() is deprecated.

snippet of models.py

```
class MyProfile(UserenaBaseProfile):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                unique=True,
                                verbose_name=_('user'),
                                related_name='my_profile')
    storename=models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=20)
```

So how would I replace

```
extra_context['profile'] = user.get_profile()
```

extra_context['profile'] = user.my_profile ?

Comment: Yes, exactly that, because you set the related_name.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specific_user.my_profile.all() ?